# How to know when a dynamically loaded CSS file is fully loaded and active?

Tags: javascript, css, lazy-loading

I have used a technique described in [a post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744270/dynamically-loading-css) to dynamically add a CSS file to the HEAD tag of an HTML page (in JavaScript). The method to check whether the CSS file has been fully loaded (see the same post) is described by its author as 'ugly' and in my opinion it is ;-) Yet [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488567/is-there-any-way-to-detect-when-a-css-file-has-been-fully-loaded) suggests using a 'lazy loader' (see the accepted answer in that post) that takes cross-browser issues into account. Though the code looks fine, is seems rather complex for the task at hand.

My question is: More than a year after the post that I have last mentioned (and a lot of improvements in browser techniques), is there a reliable, cross-browser way to check whether a dynamically loaded CSS file is ready to use?

Comment: One more point: I would prefer a non-Ajax (non-XHR) method and also  not to use any JavaScript library, unless there is no other way.

Comment: Does this mean you don't have to support any older browsers?

Comment: I have to support modern browsers only.

Answer (score 0):

try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/LucuV/2/)

```
(function() {
    function cssLoader(url) {
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.onload = function(){
            console.log('loaded');
        };
        link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link)
    }

    cssLoader('http://jsfiddle.net/css/style.css');

}());​
```

Comment: I have tried the jsFiddle, but it doesn't seem to work in Chrome (17) and IE 9. I don't think those browsers actually support the onload event on a (dynamic) link element. I think at least IE needs the onreadystatechange event. The lazy loader that I have mentioned in my question (https://github.com/LukeTheDuke/Lazyloader/blob/master/lazyloader.js) uses both onload and onreadystatechange.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by loading your CSS file with an `img`.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.onerror = function()
{
    console.log("loaded");
}

img.src = url;
```

More information here: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2011/03/20/link-tag-css-stylesheet-load-event/