# How to fire the JavaScript resize event after all CSS layout changes

Tags: javascript, css

I want the JavaScript resize event to be fired AFTER all the css changes (of a responsive Bootstrap layout) are completed. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems that is not possible to detect when a CSS file is full loaded, just with some libraries. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488567/is-there-any-way-to-detect-when-a-css-file-has-been-fully-loaded

Answer (score 0):

The `window.onload` event is fired when the site, including the CSS files, is completly loaded.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: But it's only fired once when the page has been loaded. I'm looking for a way also layout modifications (like Bootstraps responsive changes after viewport resizes) are catched.

Comment: It's a crappy solution, but if the layout modifications need a certain time to finish, you can call the JS-function with a delay: `setTimeout(myfunc, time)`.

Comment: It works this way - little crappy as you said, but it works and I've no better solution right now.